# Unable to save the custom model to .pb format (tensorflow 2.1.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to convert from a Keras model (.h5/json) with custom layers to tensorflow model (.pb) and I use the following custom LSTM layer.

```
class AttentionVLSTMCell(AbstractRNNCell):

  def __init__(...):

    super(AttentionVLSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

...

  @property
  def state_size(self):
    return [self.timestep*self.att_input_dim, self.units]

  def build(self, input_shape): # difinition of the weights

...

  @tf.function
  def _time_distributed_dense(self, x, w, b=None, dropout=None,
                              input_dim=None, output_dim=None,
                              timesteps=None, training=None):
    if input_dim is None:
        input_dim = K.shape(x)[2]
    if timesteps is None:
        timesteps = K.shape(x)[1]
    if output_dim is None:
        output_dim = K.shape(w)[1]

    if dropout is not None and 0. < dropout < 1.:
        # apply the same dropout pattern at every timestep
        ones = K.ones_like(K.reshape(x[:, 0, :], (-1, input_dim)))
        dropout_matrix = K.dropout(ones, dropout)
        expanded_dropout_matrix = K.repeat(dropout_matrix, timesteps)
        x = K.in_train_phase(x * expanded_dropout_matrix, x, training=training)

    # collapse time dimension and batch dimension together
    x = K.reshape(x, (-1, input_dim))
    x = K.dot(x, w)
    if b is not None:
        x = K.bias_add(x, b)
    # reshape to 3D tensor
    if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
        x = K.reshape(x, K.stack([-1, timesteps, output_dim]))
        x.set_shape([None, None, output_dim])
    else:
        x = K.reshape(x, (-1, timesteps, output_dim))
    return x

  def _compute_update_vertex(self, x, V_tm1, c):
    """Computes carry and output using split kernels."""
    # x = W * track
    x_i, x_f, x_c, x_o = x
    V_tm1_i, V_tm1_f, V_tm1_c, V_tm1_o, V_tm1_o2, V_tm1_u, V_tm1_v = V_tm1
    c_i, c_f, c_c, c_o = c
    # i = x_i + V_tm1_i * R_i
    #   = W_i * track + V_tm1_i * R_i + C_i * context
    
    print(x_i)
    print(V_tm1_i)
    print(c_i)
    i = self.recurrent_activation(
        x_i 
        + K.dot(V_tm1_i, self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units])
        + K.dot(c_i, self.context_kernel[:, :self.units]))

    f = self.recurrent_activation(
        x_f 
        + K.dot(V_tm1_f, self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units:self.units * 2])
        + K.dot(c_f, self.context_kernel[:, self.units:self.units * 2]))

    c = self.activation(
        x_c 
        + K.dot(V_tm1_c, self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2:self.units * 3])
        + K.dot(c_c, self.context_kernel[:, self.units * 2:self.units * 3]))
    
    # U = update vertex
    U = f * V_tm1_u + i * c

    o = self.recurrent_activation(
        x_o 
        + K.dot(V_tm1_o, self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 3:])
        + K.dot(c_o, self.context_kernel[:, self.units * 3:]))

    h_temp = o * self.activation(V_tm1_o2)
    # h size [self.units]
    h = self.dense_activation(K.dot(h_temp, self.dense_kernel))
    # h size [1] activated sigmoid
    
    #the size of h is [units]
    V = h * U + (1-h) * V_tm1_v
    return h, V

  def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
    # store the whole sequence so we can "attend" to it at each timestep

    att = states[0] # Attention input (track num, input dim)
    self.x_seq = K.reshape(att, (-1, self.timestep, self.att_input_dim)) # Attention input (track num, input dim)
    V_tm1 = states[1] # previous Vertex state (units)

    # Additive Attention Bahdanau et al., 2015 
    # apply the a dense layer over the time dimension of the sequence
    # do it here because it doesn't depend on any previous steps
    # thefore we can save computation time:
    self._uxpb = self._time_distributed_dense(self.x_seq, 
                                              self.attention_kernel_U, 
                                              b=self.attention_kernel_b,
                                              input_dim=self.att_input_dim,
                                              timesteps=self.timestep,
                                              output_dim=self.units)

    # repeat the input track to the length of the sequence (track num, feature dim))
    _tt = K.repeat(inputs, self.timestep)
    _Wxtt = K.dot(_tt, self.attention_kernel_W)
    et = K.dot(activations.tanh(_Wxtt + self._uxpb), K.expand_dims(self.attention_kernel_V))
    """
    #Dot-Product Attention Luong et al., 2015 / Scaled Dot-Product Attention Vaswani 2017
    self.x_seq /= np.sqrt(self.att_input_dim)
    et = K.batch_dot(K.expand_dims(inputs), self.x_seq, axes=[1, 2])
    et = K.reshape(et, (-1, self.timestep, 1))
    """

    at = K.exp(et)
    at_sum = K.sum(at, axis=1)
    at_sum_repeated = K.repeat(at_sum, self.timestep)
    at /= at_sum_repeated  # attention weights ({batchsize}, track num, 1)
    context = K.squeeze(K.batch_dot(at, self.x_seq, axes=1), axis=1)
   

    if self.implementation == 1:
      # input = track
      inputs_i = inputs
      inputs_f = inputs
      inputs_c = inputs
      inputs_o = inputs
      # k = W
      k_i, k_f, k_c, k_o = array_ops.split(
              self.kernel, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)
      x_i = K.dot(inputs_i, k_i)
      x_f = K.dot(inputs_f, k_f)
      x_c = K.dot(inputs_c, k_c)
      x_o = K.dot(inputs_o, k_o)
      if self.use_bias:
        b_i, b_f, b_c, b_o = array_ops.split(
            self.bias, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=0)
        x_i = K.bias_add(x_i, b_i)
        x_f = K.bias_add(x_f, b_f)
        x_c = K.bias_add(x_c, b_c)
        x_o = K.bias_add(x_o, b_o)

      V_tm1_i = V_tm1
      V_tm1_f = V_tm1
      V_tm1_c = V_tm1
      V_tm1_o = V_tm1
      V_tm1_o2 = V_tm1
      V_tm1_u = V_tm1
      V_tm1_v = V_tm1

      c_i = context
      c_f = context
      c_c = context
      c_o = context

      x = (x_i, x_f, x_c, x_o)
      V_tm1 = (V_tm1_i, V_tm1_f, V_tm1_c, V_tm1_o, V_tm1_o2, V_tm1_u, V_tm1_v)
      c = (c_i, c_f, c_c, c_o)

      h, V = self._compute_update_vertex(x, V_tm1, c)

    return [h, at], [att, V]

  def get_config(self):

...

  def get_initial_state(self, inputs=True, batch_size=True, dtype=None):

...
```

I can load the model with custom layers and also can use it on the tensorflow.keras.
However I get the following issue when I try to `loaded_model.save(model_name, save_format="tf")`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr7/s70087f/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1619, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul_7' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [256], [256,256].
```

There is a issue in a V_tm1_i (calculation for the input gate of LSTM with Attention):

```
    i = self.recurrent_activation(
        x_i 
        + K.dot(V_tm1_i, self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units])
        + K.dot(c_i, self.context_kernel[:, :self.units]))
```

I know that we have to use the tensor >= 2 ndims to 'MatMul', but actually it has a batch size dimension.
Therefore I want it to become `[None,256], [256,256]`.

The inputs and hidden state of custom layer are shown:

```
AttentionVLSTM
inputs
Tensor("model/Decoder_Attention_VLSTM/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
states
(<tf.Tensor 'model/reshape/Reshape:0' shape=(None, 27136) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'model/Decoder_Activation_2/Relu:0' shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32>)
AttentionVLSTM
inputs
Tensor("TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem:0", shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
states
(<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(None, 27136) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32>)
AttentionVLSTM
inputs
Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
states
(<tf.Tensor 'states:0' shape=(27136,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'states_1:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>)
```

V_tm1 is obtained from hidden state, and "Placeholder_4:0" is the correct shape `[None,256]` but "states_1:0" lost the dimension of batch axis `[256,]`.
Other custom layers (except this layer) can be operating and this layer is also working in tensorflow.Keras.

Batch size = 32 (the states:0 and inputs:0 are not output)

```
AttentionVLSTM
inputs
Tensor("model/Decoder_Attention_VLSTM/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(32, 256), dtype=float32)
states
(<tf.Tensor 'model/reshape/Reshape:0' shape=(32, 27136) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'model/Decoder_Activation_2/Relu:0' shape=(32, 256) dtype=float32>)
AttentionVLSTM
inputs
Tensor("TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem:0", shape=(32, 256), dtype=float32)
states
(<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0' shape=(32, 27136) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0' shape=(32, 256) dtype=float32>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue. The cause of error is the definition of initial state at the end of this custom class. It is unnecessary because that the initial state was already defined at "AbstractRNNCell".